# What does Module.private_constant do? Is there a way to list only private constants?

Tags: ruby, constants, private, ruby-1.9.3

Starting in Ruby 1.9.3, we can create private constants:

```
module M
  class C; end
  private_constant :C
end
```

Is there a good documentation about what this does? Is there a way to get the names of only private constants similar to calling `constants`

Comment: Please explain what use of this you're planning to get.

Comment: Ruby doesn't have private constants. The closest you can get is a class variable, but that isn't terribly private, as it is shared with all subclasses.

Comment: @RyanBigg I do not have any use for it. I do not understand the relevance of your question to my question.

Comment: @sawa Because if you had an actual purpose, and told us, we might have an idea using something Ruby *does* support. Knowing *why* someone wants something is generally valuable, particularly when it's something that doesn't immediately make sense.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Why did you remove the Ruby 1.9.3 tag? This is a feature specific to Ruby 1.9.3. Or did it exist from before that? Please explain.

Comment: @Linuxios Then, what does `class A; B = 5; private_constant :B; end` mean?

Comment: @DaveNewton I am not wanting something. I am just asking how private constants work. I don't understand what you are mentioning by "something that doesn't immediately make sense".

Comment: @sawa ... You're wanting to know how private constants work. Since there's only barely privacy at all, and private constants were added only recently, most people will try to figure out *why* you want to know so something else can be suggested. I find it difficult to believe this is a difficult concept to understand. And what's the big deal anyway?

Comment: @DaveNewton How can a method `private_constant` exist without private constant existing? Please explain that in detail. Your comment is totally incomprehensible.

Comment: Then how did you manage to reply to it at all?! This word, "totally"... or maybe "incomprehensible", may not mean what you think it does. Again: "private" in ruby means almost nothing, it's essentially informational. Carry on.

Comment: sawa: sorry for the misunderstanding, but this is really just a ruby 1.9.3 feature, and the question should xp.icitly state that.

Comment: @Linuxios Yes, it is Ruby 1.9.3 specific, and I had that tag. Andrew Marshall somehow removed that tag. I do not understand the reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Ruby 2.1, while `Module#constants` includes only public constants, if you set `inherit=false`, you will get private constants as well. So if you find a constant in `constants(false)` but not in `constants` (and you don't care about inherited constants), that might be a more or less reliable way to tell if it's private.

```
class Module
  def private_constants
    constants(false) - constants
  end
end

module Foo
  X = 1
  Y = 2
  private_constant :Y
end

puts "Foo.constants = #{Foo.constants}"
puts "Foo.constants(false) = #{Foo.constants(false)}"
puts "Foo.private_constants = #{Foo.private_constants}"

# => Foo.constants = [:X]
# => Foo.constants(false) = [:X, :Y]
# => Foo.private_constants = [:Y]
```

This is undocumented, and I'm not sure if it's intentional, but empirically it works. I would back it up with unit tests.

---

**Update:** It looks like this is [a bug in Ruby](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12345), and may disappear in a future version.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that. But that looks strange. It might be a Ruby's bug.

Comment: @sawa Looks like the bug was accepted. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 11):

There is no such thing as private constants until Ruby 1.9.3. To get a list of all the constants though, you can simply use `constants`.

```
module Mod
  CONST = "value"
end

Mod.constants #=> [:CONST]
```

From 1.9.3, `private_constant` was added, but as nothing is really private, you can do...

```
module Mod
  CONST = "value"
  private_constant :CONST
end

Mod.const_get(:CONST) #=> "value"
```

I don't think there is a way of getting a list of all the private constants but you can still test the presence of a particular name.

```
Mod.const_defined?(:CONST) #=> true
```

Comment: Then what does the following code mean? `class A; B = 5; private_constant :B; end`

Comment: With your edit, the second half of your answer contradicts the first half.

Comment: That's because I wrote "in Ruby 1.9.3" instead of "until Ruby 1.9.3" ;-)

Comment: @sawa: I think it means that you can't use the normal scope resoulurion operator to get the constant. Think of private methods, and how they can still be accessed with `send`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Please explain why you removed the ruby-1.9.3 tag from my question.