# Iterate over only public Ruby constants

Tags: ruby, private-members

Since Ruby 2.0 or so, it's been possible to make a constant private using [`private_constant`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Module.html#method-i-private_constant), resulting in an error if the constant is used directly outside the declaring module.

However, [`constants`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Module.html#method-i-constants) and [`const_defined?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Module.html#method-i-const_defined-3F) still return private constants, and [`const_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Module.html#method-i-const_get) allows access to them. Is there a way to programmatically identify private constants and filter them out at run time?

(Note: [What does Module.private_constant do? Is there a way to list only private constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12944616/27358) and its answer don't specifically address this case, but rather the reverse (how to list only *private* constants).)

---

**Update:** It looks as though in Ruby 1.9 and 2.0, `constants` did include only public constants. As of 2.1, the no-arg `constants` still includes only public constants, but setting `inherit` to `false` with `constants(false)` (i.e., list only constants defined in this module, not in its ancestor modules) has the side effect of exposing the private constants.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944616/what-does-module-private-constant-do-is-there-a-way-to-list-only-private-consta

Comment: They are still defined. Do you want Ruby to lie?

Comment: I'm not replicating your problem in Ruby 2.1.4: `2.1.4 :001 > module Foo;   X = 1;  Y = 2; private_constant :Y;  end; Foo.constants` returns `[:X]`

Comment: @tadman No, I'm just noting what I've tried.

Comment: @NeilSlater That's interesting. When I try to reduce it to a minimal test case, I'm not seeing it either.

Comment: @DavidMoles: If you have some code that manipulates constants, maybe as part of framework, it may delete and re-add them. I guess that may remove the private flag if the code wasn't aware it needed to preserve them. I read the source for `private_constant` and the flag appears to be added directly to the constant (it is not a separate lookup), so if you delete a constant, you implicitly delete its private flag status.

Comment: @NeilSlater It looks like it's related to the `inherit` flag -- see edits.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth That question is related but is actually the opposite of what I'm trying to do, and its current answer isn't entirely correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can identify constants by next way:

```
class A
  C = "value"
  private_constant :C
  C2 = "value2"
end

A.constants #public constants
#=> [:C2]
A.constants(false) #public & private constants
#=> [:C, :C2]
A.constants(false) - A.constants #private constants
#=> [:C]
```

Comment: OP appears to want array of non-private constants, and is saying that `constants` method returns *all* constants (they want to filter out privite constants). I agree however, that this works, and also `A.constants` returns `[:C2]` as expected - and what OP appears to want - so not entirely sure what the OP's actual problem is.

Comment: @NeilSlater, I answered on answer `Is there a way to programmatically identify private constants?`

Comment: New edit shows all possible ways. Cannot argue with that :-) I wonder why question says that this doesn't work for OP?

Comment: @NeilSlater I was passing `(false)` in the code where I thought I had the problem. It wasn't obvious that `inherit=` had anything to do with public/private, so I didn't see that might be an issue.